# Not able to download all nuget package using solution specific nuget.config

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I'm using "nuget.config" at the same folder level where my visual studio solution file is residing. Getting expected behavior for downloading the nuget package after opening/building the application. Not all nuget packages are getting downloaded from the same nuget package feed, while only two of them are downloaded(below screenshot with **red color "checkmark"**).

[image]

The nuget.config file is as below for reference,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="..\Packages" />
     <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="..\Packages" />
  </config>
  <packageSources>
        <clear />
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\" />
        <add key="privateFeed" value="https://xyzpqrs.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/privatefeed/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
    <packageRestore>
        <add key="enabled" value="true" />
        <add key="automatic" value="true" />
    </packageRestore>
    <activePackageSource>    
        <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
    </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

Not sure why only those 2 packages are getting downloaded(they both have June dates).

Help me understand why I'm seeing this behavior and how can I download all the nuget packages from this feed or specific package with version number using "nuget.config" file.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve/found workaround for the problem using below steps,

- Open command prompt and run "dotnet nuget locals all --clear" command to clear cached nuget packages
- Delete "bin" & "obj" folders for solution
- Create/modify solution specific "nuget.config" file with nuget package location to download
- Run "Clean Solution" from VS IDE after opening VS solution
- Refactor/migrate project specific "packages.config" file to "PackageReference"